# Can't generate entity from YML in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

My entity code:

```
GameShelf\GamesBundle\Entity\Game:
    type: entity
    table: games
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        parent_id:
            type: integer
            length: 11
        name:
            type: string
            length: 200
        slug:
            type: string
            length: 200
        reldate:
            type: date
        genres:
            type: text
        platforms:
            type: text
        developers:
            type: text
        desc:
            type: text
        desc_src:
            type: text
        rate:
            string: integer
            lenght: 10
```

I run `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities GameShelf\GamesBundle\Entity\Game` and it returns `Namespace "GameShelf\GamesBundle\Entity\Game" does not contain any mapped entities.`. What's wrong? I followed [the docs here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Comment: I once created a yaml file called reservation.yml, with correct mapping information and got the same error until I found that I named the file incorrectly: it should be reservation.orm.yml ... it was so annoying, hope helps someone!

Answer (score 7):

Please see the following code for your Game.orm.yml file.

```
GameShelf\GamesBundle\Entity\Game:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    parent_id:
      type: integer
      length: 11
    name:
      type: string
      length: 200
    slug:
      type: string
      length: 200
    reldate:
      type: datetime
    genres:
      type: text
    platforms:
      type: text
    developers:
      type: text
    desc:
      type: text
    desc_src:
      type: text
    rate:
      type: integer
      length: 10
```

The following things were corrected that may help solve your issue.

- Your id declaration was wonky.
- Typo in 'length' for column 'rate'
- No such type 'date', only 'datetime'
- Looks like your using 4 space tabs, YAML calls for 2 space tabs

Tested the correct YAML on my own configuration and was able to create the entity with the following commands:

```
app/console generate:doctrine:entities --no-backup <Your Bundle>
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```